# Variables aren't listed in pycharm toolbar

Tags: python, variables, ide, pycharm, toolbar

I have been working on pycharm over the summer and I hardly know whats going on anymore.

When I run a code the tool bar doesn't list any of the variables. For instance:

```
t = 1
print(t)
```

Nowhere in the toolbar does it display the variable whereas it did last summer when I used it. It only shows a 'special variables' folder with a bunch of random stuff in it.

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question but I could figure it out in any other threads.

Thanks,
-Evan

Comment: You mean run code in the python console tab? Or run code when at a debug breakpoint?

Comment: Are you sure that t isn't under special variables?

Comment: I ran the code in the python console and no variables appear. I hardly know what breakpoints do and I wouldn't know where to put one. Also I'm sure it's not in special variables if I recall the last time I used it correctly.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you mean? its not clear from your comment or description, the python console of pycharm has no associated "variable view" unless you are in debug mode (at least that im aware of after using it extensively for several years)

Comment: here is the link: https://imgur.com/gallery/zUvDBiU

Comment: I feel silly ... anyway i just tested and did `x=6` and sure enough x showed up ... so i got nothing except "works for me"

Comment: Could you show me how to install pycharm so that stuff like this doesn’t happen? I’m only doing this for a school project I can hardly fix any of my problems...

Comment: You need to write the code in the terminal to see the variables... not in a file

Comment: How do I write in the terminal?

Comment: type it where you see `>>>` in the bottom left pannel

Comment: I found the variables by pressing structure, but I can't see the >>> in the terminal just the console... https://imgur.com/a/ViP6KRI

Comment: Also now that I can see the variables I need to be able to view the array in one of them, I used to be able to open a tab to see this massive 124x124 grid.

Comment: here .... https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmRsK.png

Comment: lol sorry for this but how do you run it

Comment: dude I did it thanks so much

Comment: cool website by the way